# Test class constructors not executing when running an xUnit Theory individually?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net

Toy example code:

```
public abstract class testBase
{
  public testBase()
  {
    //Some common test setup code, which will initialize ManagerClass
  }
}

public class someTests: testBase
{
  public someTests()
  {
    //someTests-specific constructor code.
  }

  [Theory]
  [PropertyData("MyTestData")]
  public void test1(Foo foo)
  {
    //Use foo to do a test
  }

  public static IEnumerable<object[]> MyTestData
  {
    get
    {
      yield return new object[] { ManagerClass.CreateANewFoo(1) };
      yield return new object[] { ManagerClass.CreateANewFoo(42) };
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, if I specifically run test1 (I'm using Resharper, but the problem also occurs when I use the xUnit GUI) my test is failing because it seems that neither the testBase nor someTests constructors are being executed. Hence the call to ManagerClass.CreateANewFoo() is throwing a NullReference.

If I run all of the tests in someTests, or any other individual test, the constructor executes as expected and the tests proceed in the expected fashion. The only thing that marks test1 out as different is the fact that it is using the PropertyData attribute.

Any ideas why this is happening/what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Disclaimer:Don't use xUnit.net. Did you try put Console.WriteLine/trace statements in the ctors? Are you sure that the ctor is not being invoked.. because I dont see how it can run a test without creating an instance of the test fixture/class. Sounds like a bug to me if Run All Tests / Run One Test result in different test output. Try: If the ctors are being hit, try using fake values instead of the return of a static method ? Are tests run in different AppDomains in xUnit.net

Comment: Putting Console.WriteLine statements in shows the constructors executing when the test is run as part of the whole class. But debugging individually (with a breakpoint at the Writeline statements) the first thing I encounter in the debugger is the NullReference being thrown, not the breakpoints.

Comment: That could be because your static MyTestData method is being invoked before the test is run for some reason - since you dont have to construct the object to invoke a static method. This test-fixture design makes me a bit uncomfortable - the static method is depending on a base class ctor in order to run correctly. Can the PropertyData method be an instance method - try moving the setup code from the base class ctor into the static method temporarily to confirm if that is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We attempted to reproduce this with xUnit.net 1.5 Beta and cannot.

Comment: After further discussion on CodePlex (http://xunit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=65564), I just need to refactor the test in light of the execution order.